# Virtual product order status after issuing invoice

Tags: order-status, virtual-products

We are selling workshops/seminars on our eshop as virtual products. If the customer purchases the workshop on its own and selects Paypal/Credit card payment, the order status immediately goes to "COMPLETED". If he selects bank transfer, the status is "PROCESSING" but after issuing invoice (we do this in bulk) it changes to "COMPLETED" as well.

This is a huge problem for us because we lose track of the order in the back end (we need to issue invoice through our external software). Is there a solution for the virtual product orders to follow the same order statuses as simple products?

Thank you ...

Answer (score 1):

The reason virtual products go to complete status after creating an invoice is because a shipment is not required as the product does not need to be physically delivered - the behaviour is deliberate.

If you have external software generating an invoice you will either have to work on integration between the two systems so that a Magento invoice is created at the point the external invoice is generated (perhaps have the external system poll a Magento URL with an order id and have some logic to generate an invoice for the order) or wait for the external system to generate the invoice and only at this point manually create the Magento invoice to complete the order.

Comment: Hello Jonathan,